# In typescript, is it possible to properly define types for a Function.prototype.bind polyfill?

Tags: typescript

I need to implement a polyfill for Function.prototype.bind, something similar to this:

```
function functionBind(fn, scope, ...bindArgs) {
    return function (...args) {
        const boundArgs = bindArgs || [];
        const callerArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) || [];

        return fn.apply(scope, boundArgs.concat(callerArgs));
    };
}
```

However, I'm having a hard time implementing proper types for this. In the end, I'd need something that takes the parameters of the given function as a tuple, and from that tuple I'd need a type that misses some entries at the beginning (depending on how many arguments are provided to the bind function), to return a proper type for the resulting function.

Is there a way I can get something like a partial tuple? Is it even possible to type this function properly, especially if all strict compiler options are enabled?

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to take an item out of a tuple (there are recursive conditional type solutions but I would not necessarily use them). The way `bind` works in typescript (when [`--strictBindCallApply`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028) is turned on) is by having several overloads, up to a number of parameters it is reasonable to bind:

```
    bind<T>(this: T, thisArg: ThisParameterType<T>): OmitThisParameter<T>;
    bind<T, A0, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0): (...args: A) => R;
    bind<T, A0, A1, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1): (...args: A) => R;
    bind<T, A0, A1, A2, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2): (...args: A) => R;
    bind<T, A0, A1, A2, A3, A extends any[], R>(this: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, ...args: A) => R, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3): (...args: A) => R;
    bind<T, AX, R>(this: (this: T, ...args: AX[]) => R, thisArg: T, ...args: AX[]): (...args: AX[]) => R;
```

You can use a similar aproach:

```
function functionBind<T>(fn: T, thisArg: ThisParameterType<T>): OmitThisParameter<T>;
function functionBind<T, A0, A extends any[], R>(fn: (this: T, arg0: A0, ...args: A) => R, scope: T, arg0: A0): (...args: A) => R;
function functionBind<T, A0, A1, A extends any[], R>(fn: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, ...args: A) => R, scope: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1): (...args: A) => R;
function functionBind<T, A0, A1, A2, A extends any[], R>(fn: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, ...args: A) => R, scope: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2): (...args: A) => R;
function functionBind<T, A0, A1, A2, A3, A extends any[], R>(fn: (this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, ...args: A) => R, scope: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3): (...args: A) => R;
function functionBind<T, AX, R>(fn: (this: T, ...args: AX[]) => R, scope: T, ...args: AX[]): (...args: AX[]) => R;
function functionBind<T>(fn: (this: T, ...args: any[]) => any, scope: T, ...bindArgs: any[]) {
    return function (...args: any[]) {
        const boundArgs = bindArgs || [];
        const callerArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) || [];

        return fn.apply(scope, boundArgs.concat(callerArgs));
    };
}

function test(a: string, b: number) {

}

var r = functionBind(test, null, "")  // (b: number) => void
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=42&pln=10&pc=68#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSsECEZgCYB4AqAfABTBgBci+ANIlABYwDOAggE4Dml+jTACgEM2AgLYBTKGLb4AngAcxBQgEpKAeREwoPZoOHjJbJQG4AsACgU0eEitowmHAVosADC8RiAHpJxNEAmAyANoAurQASiRklMQMzNy0QhyulG60AHRZyUxpyogAvISIEbRMEHAKiQGcqYhuqojEWRk5eYXFEWaW4NYIyL32jng09e71AIwe3r7Y-oEh4SXRFE3xuVRJtWnjyRNpU4gtbfX5RSVlFVWbNSk7Wxz7k43N2ZwbLGed3XY2A6g2YbOMYuQ4sABM0x8Yj8ASCYUiK1i62qyTq6VuTxYh2S4LSkKObw4Hy+F0Q5UqYlR2xBmIODzx9XBL2O73a5y6Fl+-W5DiwIxc42xLgJLAAzFDZvN4UsoqRVnFeNS7rS9vTboyIQ8xWkJYTWmzTh0yRTrqM0fc6ZMGfjtbqWUSScbOT0ATzBoD+cCWAANRHy5FKm6s4lpH1hUmlclXKnBx1hiOxEMfcOhSM-D3ut18pxEANrIOjZOUBYR40LS6U6otABG-PYobhi3yAG8LIgO4g2BIQGxbJmkK8DY3S2nEG3zJ2p4gKmAmFBEDW4OBsA3-AVF-X3ogAD47xBhbrTzuz+czgQAGwvUjXhXqbGEMgycjYcCgb-kYgyTAvMAgX4gS8L2IZIQHEMAoCYfI9wPUJunbY8ux7PtkDAVo5DkC8ZGIU0xFoJcVzXDJZ0AqBiEAq8b3eZRlCPTsAF9unoiwuQHOgxHnEDKHnNgsA4fDKDAMCaykVsEI7CxmPMCwADchC7O9eWGOIOKgWghKvWgACItPyRAAHp9KaGtBOE0TjRkuAYGwIA)